# Removing spaces from a EUR currency string in Java

Tags: java, numbers, currency, number-formatting, spaces

I have a method that convert a number into a currency, for "USD" and "GBP" it's working good, but with "EUR" the NumberFormat it's rendering a string with a space between the symbol and the number `€ 1.207.987,00` rather then dollar and pound `"$1,207,987.00"`, `"£1,207,987.00"`. I tried use replace and replace all to remove this but nothing works for me, follow the code:

```
 public static void main(String[] argsd) {
        Number rawNumber = 120798700;
         NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("nl"));
         Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
         numberFormat.setCurrency(currency);
         String numberRemoveSpaces = numberFormat.format((rawNumber.floatValue() / 100)).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println(numberRemoveSpaces);
    }
```

Comment: That might actually be a legitimate difference between how currency values are written in the given locale (the CLDR is usually pretty precise about stuff like that), so removing that whitespace might actually make your formatting less correct. Also note that your USD and GBP strings use different decimal indicators so they don't come from the same Locale.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it, try this:

```
String numberRemoveSpaces = numberFormat.format((rawNumber.floatValue() / 100)).replaceAll("\\p{Z}","");
```

That removes any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.

Comment: By the way, I only changed your `replaceAll` method. I put it all for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, instead of your current `replaceAll()`:

```
replaceFirst("\\u00A0", "")
```

The Unicode value of U+00A0 is a non-breaking space (see [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)). This is the specific character being used to separate the currency symbol from the amount.

You can also choose to build a custom format as follows:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("€");
dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
dfs.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator(',');
((DecimalFormat) nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
System.out.println(nf.format(rawNumber.floatValue() / 100));
```

This also gives the same output:

```
€1.207.987,00
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the answers but according with http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2013/11/formatting-dutch-currency-amounts/ the default format for Netherlands currency have the space between the symbol and number, so i'll keep with the space.